# Object.keys but not in order JS / TS

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have a problem : **I have this JSON =>**

```
const json = {
  "test" : "...",
  "3" : "...",
  "go" : "...",
  "38" : "..."
}
```

And when I do :

```
const returned = Object.keys(json);
```

And *returned* have this inside :

```
3,38,go,test
```

In alphabetic order ! And I just want the *returned* in "classic" order.
Do you have a solution ?

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: It looks like information about keys order is not stored anywhere https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/

Comment: https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html#traversing-the-own-keys-of-an-object might be useful. In Chrome, Reflect.ownKeys(json) gives me ["3","38","test","go"]

Comment: That's the same as `Object.keys`.

Comment: Yes: I was meaning to point out that the order is apparently fixed, but that integers come first, then strings in chronological order... .so the problem is only there apparently because of the integer-like-strings. Also "test" and "go" are the other way around to the OP's "go" and "test". The problem might be half-soluble, depending on specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can tolerate having leading zeros on the integer keys in the json, you could get it to work something like this:

```js
const json = {
  "test" : "...",
  "03" : "...",
  "go" : "...",
  "038" : "..."
}
console.log(Object.keys(json))   //  ["test", "03", "go", "038"] in Chrome at least
```

The article [here](https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html#traversing-the-own-keys-of-an-object) explains the ordering of object keys. Essentially, integers and integer-like strings go before strings, but string go in chronological order (order of insertion). If you put a leading zero on an (string) integer, it is treated as a string, not an integer, for the purposes of ordering.

This behaviour is I think dependent on the JS engine, but it is specified I think in ES6.

Answer (score 2):

**Use a Map if insertion order matters**

If insertion order matters use a [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), a map will retain the insertion order according the spec.

**Demo**

```js
let map = new Map();
map.set('test', '...');
map.set('3', '...');
map.set('go', '...');
map.set('38', '...');

for( key of map.keys() )
  console.log( key )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object to iterate through keys in insertion order. As the MDN docs say,

> The Map object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original insertion order of the keys. Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value. ....
> a `for...of` loop returns an array of [key, value] for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little hack by adding `+` to object number keys like shown below and then transform them to numbers again:

```
const json = {
  test: "...",
  "+3": "...",
  go: "...",
  "+38": "...",
};

for (let key in json) {
  let value = json[key];
  if (key[0] === "+") {
    key = +key;
  }

  console.log(key + ": " + value);
}
```